# Insert newline in django form using forms.py

Tags: python, django

I am making a login form in django. This is my `forms.py`:

```py
from django import forms
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect

class loginForm(forms.Form):
    email_id = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField(max_length=32, widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    forms.CharField(required=True)
```

My question is, how can I insert a newline in between `email_id` and `password`?
Because the page looks like this:
[image]

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

My template:

```
<!Doctype html>
<head><title> Login-</title></head>
<body>
<form action = "/login-form/" method = "post">
{{ login }}
<input type  = "submit" value = "Login">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please show your template? You might be rendering your form as `{{ form.as_p }}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can render you form field by field manually, like this:

```
<!Doctype html>
<head><title> Login-</title></head>
<body>
<form action = "/login-form/" method = "post">
{{ login.email_id }}
<div> your new line goes here</div>

{{ login.password }}
<input type  = "submit" value = "Login">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

More info about [Rendering Fields Manually](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually)